# Only Add Visible Columns To Data Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have an asp:gridview on my page and I am wanting to only add visible columns to my datatable.

I currently use this to add the data to the datatable - how would I pose a check if the column is visible?

```
DataRow dr = dtforgrid.NewRow();
for (int i = 1; i < gridma.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dr[i-1] = row.Cells[i].Text; 
}
dtforgrid.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: Show your Gridview code. It is a template or "DataKeyNames" with "SqlDataSource" or something else? Show your complete c# code and gridview template code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use GridViewRow type inside your loop, it has a property tocheck if a column is visible or not.

```
foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
{
   if(item.Cells[0].Visible)
   {
                // do something
   }
}
```